# CUDA: vector list implementation

Tags: c++, algorithm, list, vector, cuda

I'm running an algorithm in CUDA which takes as input a list of triangles, then tries to voxelize them on a grid, and the output should be the list of grid cells that are touched by triangles. Of course, this list will vary in size depending on the input triangles. I know the upper bound of the size of the list (gridsize x gridsize x gridsize).

The problem is, allocating a big table of all possible grid cells, and marking true/false in that table is cumbersome and takes a lot of memory. Also, CUDA atomic operations only work on 32/64bit values, which would be overkill for a simple boolean flag.

On the host, I would add grid cells marked as filled to a vector, then sort the vector and remove the duplicates.

Is there any way / algorithm for CUDA for storing a variable-sized list?

Answer (score 2):

You could use more-or-less the same method as your sequential version, just using parallel implementations of your primitives (sort, unique).

The easiest way to get started is to look at using [Thrust](http://thrust.github.io), the [weld vertices example](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/blob/master/examples/weld_vertices.cu) should get you started with the syntax, the outline would look like this:

1. Use the `thrust::transform` algorithm to transform the list of triangles into a list of grid cells
2. Define a comparison operator to define the ordering of grid cells
3. Use the comparison operator with the `thrust::sort` algorithm to sort the list of grid cells
4. Use `thrust::unique` to remove duplicates

Comment: The problem is, I cannot use Thrust primitives in a GPU kernel. And the math-heavy part (deciding whether or not a triangle belongs to a grid cell) is implemented in a kernel.

Comment: My suggestion was to use `thrust::transform` to run the classification code, i.e. implement the decision as a functor and pass that to `transform`. To put it another way, your classification code takes the triangles as input and outputs a list of grid cells, then you do the sort, then remove duplicates.